# Python: Get most frequent item in list

Tags: python, list, group-by, max

Given a list of tuples, I'm looking to get the most frequently occurring tuple BUT if there are "joint winners" it should pick between them at random.

```
tups = [ (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (1,2), (3,4) ]
```

The above list should return either `(1,2)` or `(3,4)` at random for the above list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first use Counter to find the most repeated tuple. Then find the required tuples and finally randomize and get the first value.

```
from collections import Counter
import random

tups = [ (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (1,2), (3,4) ]
lst = Counter(tups).most_common()
highest_count = max([i[1] for i in lst])
values = [i[0] for i in lst if i[1] == highest_count]
random.shuffle(values)
print values[0]
```

Comment: @Juddling actually, you don't need most_common() - see my answer

Comment: @RomanPekar I see, why would I want to avoid using most_common()?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, most_common() will sort the whole list and you just need the maximum frequency

Answer (score 14):

Use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> collections.Counter([ (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (1,2), (3,4) ]).most_common()[0]
((1, 2), 2)
```

This is `O(n log(n))`.

Comment: actually if you need most frequent item, it's possible to do in O(n). You just count frequencies, get max and then get all items with highest frequencies. at least 4 people don't know that :)

Comment: It's not possible to do this in O(n), counting all frequencies by itself requires some kind of hash table.

Comment: AFAIK Counter is implemented as a dictionary and setting element of dictionary is `O(1)` in average. In your answer `most_common()` method will do the sort of all elements so it would be most heavy part - O(n log(n))

Answer (score 1):

You can first sort the list to get the tuples sorted by frequency. After that a linear scan can get you the most frequent tuple from the list. Overall time `O(nlogn)`

```
>>> tups = [ (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (1,2), (3,4) ]
>>> 
>>> sorted(tups)
[(1, 2), (1, 2), (3, 4), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should do your task in `o(n)` time:

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> from collections import Counter
>>>
>>> tups = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (1,2), (3,4)]
>>> c = Counter(tups)                            # count frequencies
>>> m = max(v for _, v in c.iteritems())         # get max frq
>>> r = [k for k, v in c.iteritems() if v == m]  # all items with highest frq
>>> shuffle(r)                                   # if you really need random - shuffle
>>> print r[0]
(3, 4)
```

Comment: This is not `O(n)`, think of the case where all elements are unqiue.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity setting of element in dictionary is O(1) average

Answer (score 0):

Counting with `collections.Counter` and then random choice of the most common:

```
import collections
import random

lis = [ (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (1,2), (3,4) ]  # Test data
cmn = collections.Counter(lis).most_common()  # Numbering based on occurrence
most = [e for e in cmn if (e[1] == cmn[0][1])]  # List of those most common
print(random.choice(most)[0])  # Print one of the most common at random
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example with no imports:

```
listAlphaLtrs = ['b','a','a','b','a','c','a','a','b','c','c','b','a','a','a']
dictFoundLtrs = {i:listAlphaLtrs.count(i) for i in listAlphaLtrs}
maxcnt = 0
theltr = 0
for ltr in dictFoundLtrs:
    ltrfound = ltr
    foundcnt = dictFoundLtrs[ltr]
    if foundcnt > maxcnt:
        maxcnt = foundcnt
        theltr = ltrfound
print('most: ' + theltr)
```

**Sources:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23240989/1447509