# Python: count repeated elements in the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python. I am trying to find a simple way of getting a count of the number of elements repeated in a list e.g.

```
MyList = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "c", "a", "c"]
```

Output:

```
a: 3
b: 1
c: 3
```

Answer (score 204, accepted):

You can do that using **`count`**:

```
my_dict = {i:MyList.count(i) for i in MyList}

>>> print my_dict     #or print(my_dict) in python-3.x
{'a': 3, 'c': 3, 'b': 1}
```

**Or** using [**`collections.Counter`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

a = dict(Counter(MyList))

>>> print a           #or print(a) in python-3.x
{'a': 3, 'c': 3, 'b': 1}
```

Comment: first option result in syntax error

Comment: It raises a Syntax Error in Python 3 (print is a function), it works in 2.7.

Comment: @sshashank124 ran it against 2.6.6, should have said that sorry - nevermind!

Comment: yeah was actually complaining about for loop in the literal dict in 2.6 (see my answer for 2.6 way, not that it is relevant...)

Comment: This solution is super slow. Much faster using pandas: `pd.DataFrame(MyList, columns=["x"]).groupby('x').size().to_dict()`

Comment: Using the `.count` solution is *horribly inefficient* and an antipattern

Comment: Both of the above methods break during really big data  [like the this one](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/9060/input00.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1582846628&Signature=TF4q914E8%2F6O0T9nFFD2UqArYdU%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

Comment: I actually have never been so happy as I was finding this answer! Solved my problem perfectly. 6 years later still just as fresh :)

Comment: if you use a 'set' for get unique values in the 'for' it will go faster:
  `setList = list(set(Mylist))
  my_dict = {i:MyList.count(i) for i in setList}`

Comment: I recommend adding an efficiency comment in the actual answer for when using 'collections.Counter' vs '.count'. In larger datasets, it makes a huge difference

Answer (score 26):

Use `Counter`

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> MyList = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "c", "a", "c"]
>>> c = Counter(MyList)
>>> c
Counter({'a': 3, 'c': 3, 'b': 1})
```

Answer (score 12):

This works for Python 2.6.6

```
a = ["a", "b", "a"]
result = dict((i, a.count(i)) for i in a)
print result
```

prints

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 1}
```

Comment: +1 for compatibility with older versions.

Answer (score 7):

```
yourList = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "c", "a", "c"]
```

> expected outputs {a: 3, b: 1,c:3}

```
duplicateFrequencies = {}
for i in set(yourList):
    duplicateFrequencies[i] = yourList.count(i)
```

Cheers!! [Reference](http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2008/07/python-counting-items-in-list.html)

Answer (score 7):

```
In [2]: MyList = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "c", "a", "c"]

In [3]: count = {}

In [4]: for i in MyList:
   ...:     if not i in count:
   ...:         count[i] = 1
   ...:     else:
   ...:         count[i] +=1
   ...:

In [5]: count
Out[5]: {'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 3}
```