# Accessing key/value pairs in a dictionary created by the built-in counter function (python 3.4)

Tags: python, function, dictionary, variable-assignment, counter

So I found my answer here [Python: count repeated elements in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240969/python-count-repeated-elements-in-the-list?answertab=active#tab-top)

but I cannot find the second part of my question. Which is, how do I access a value in a dictionary created by the function, Counter? This is the code I have so far:

```
import collections
from collections import Counter
only_callers=[]
for line in infile:
    calls=line.split(';')
    index=calls[1]
    only_callers.append(index)
    count=Counter(only_callers)
for value in count:
    print(count.get[only_callers])
```

The context for this question, is that I need to count the number of times each number has called and then put that number in a table. I get the number of calls from a file called calls.txt.

So here is my output when I print calls:
    Counter({'7804922860': 502, '7801234567': 384, '7809876543': 374....})

Now when I try to access the values in the second for loop, I get this:
    TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

So how do I access(and extract) my values(each individual one) so I may place them on a table manually?

Note: The second for loop where I print the count dictionary is just to check if it works or not, and it obviously does not from the TypeError message

Comment: For each line in infile you create a count object

Comment: Yes I am. I am traversing through the elements in calls.txt

Comment: ...yet you seem to overwrite the count variable every time you go through this loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a much better way to approach this, and you can use a `Counter` just like a dictionary:

```
only_callers=[]
full_count = Counter()
for line in infile:
    calls=line.split(';')
    index=calls[1]
    only_callers.append(index)
    full_count.update(only_callers)

print full_count[<something>]
```

The issue with your first example is that you were making a new counter in each loop:

```
for line in infile:
    # make only_callers
    count=Counter(only_callers)
```

`count` wasn't referenced outside the loop, so it was created and then each loop immediately over-wrote count. Every loop over-wrote `count`

Now, I assume you actually want to keep the counts around and accumulate them. The way to do that is to instantiate a single counter before you enter the loop and update it at each point rather than creating a new object hence:

```
total_count = Counter()
for line in infile:
    total_count.update(<new_entries>)
```

Once that's done, you have your `full_count` object you can access it just like a standard dictionary (the syntax above won't work), like so:

```
total_count[<key>]
```

or

```
total_count.get(<key>, <default>)
```

The `TypeError` you were getting is because the `.get[]` syntax doesn't exist. It's like you were trying to grab the specific element of a function.