# Find the count of the occurrences of an integer in an array in Python

Tags: python, list

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161752/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-the-elements-in-a-list) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240969/python-count-repeated-elements-in-the-list).  I was wondering if I could do it without using libraries like collection, but with a simple loop structure.
Can I do this in Python?

```
void printRepeating(int arr[], int size)
{
  int *count = (int *)calloc(sizeof(int), (size - 2));
  int i;

  printf(" Repeating elements are ");
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {  
    if(count[arr[i]] == 1)
      printf(" %d ", arr[i]);
    else
     count[arr[i]]++;
  }    
}
```

I tried doing this -

```
a=[1,2,3,2,4,3,1,7,4,3];
b=[];
for i in a:
        b[i]=b[i]+1;
```

But I get

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is there a way around it?

Comment: It doesn't work because your list `b` is empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: count repeated elements in the list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240969/python-count-repeated-elements-in-the-list)

Comment: The accepted answer in your other link does that without using a library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) (Python's built-in hash map type) will be the simplest:

```
a = [1,2,3,2,4,3,1,7,4,3]
b = {}
for i in a:
    # get(key, default) falls back to default if key is not present
    b[i] = b.get(i, 0) + 1

> b
{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 2, 7: 1}
> b[3]
3
```

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Python world, you C developer! ;) You can drop the semicolons here.

Your `b` here is a Python list with 0 elements, you cannot get or set elements inside it this way: `b[i]` if an element with index i does not exist already.

But there are plenty of ways to do what you want. If you really don't want to use built-in libraries, you can try this way (should produce the exact same output as your C code):

```
a = [1,2,3,2,4,3,1,7,4,3]
print("Repeating elements are")
for i in a:
    if a.count(i) > 1:
        print(i)
```

But a `collections.Counter` is the best way to do it, it is built-in so why not use it ?

```
from collections import Counter
a = [1,2,3,2,4,3,1,7,4,3]
counter = Counter(a)
print(counter.most_common())
```

Comment: That should be `most_common()`

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you are creating `b` as a list to count the occurrences of each of the numbers in `a`. That way, you can create a dictionary that might be easier:

```
a=[1,2,3,2,4,3,1,7,4,3]
b={}
for i in a:
    if i in b:
        b[i]+=1
    else:
        b[i]=1
```

And then go through the dictionary to check for repeats.