# How to tell how many duplicates in a list?

Tags: python

Say my list is `['a', 'a', 'b']` how would I tell that the letter `a` appears twice? I know it's probably simple but I can't get my head around it...

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: This question was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240969/python-count-repeated-elements-in-the-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> a = ['a', 'a', 'b']
>>> a.count('a')
2
```