# Parsed Lists to Dictionary with 2 counter keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got a tcpdump file that I managed to split and parse to get it get information I needed: src ip+port and dst ip+port.

```
f = open('dump2.txt', 'r')
lines = f.read().splitlines(`)

for line in lines:
    line = line.split()
    if len(line) >0:
        srcIpList = line[2]
        srcIp = srcIpList.split('.')[:4]
        srcPortList = line[2]
        srcPort = srcPortList.split('.')[4:]
        dstIpList = line[4]
        dstIp = dstIpList.split('.')[:4]
        dstPortList = line[4]
        dstPort = dstPortList.split('.')[4:]
```

Output:

```
['142', '55', '1', '9'] ['80'] ['142', '55', '186', '239'] ['1220:']
['142', '55', '194', '76'] ['3956'] ['142', '55', '1', '9'] ['80:']
['142', '55', '1', '9'] ['80'] ['142', '55', '149', '106'] ['1591:']
['142', '55', '186', '239'] ['1220'] ['142', '55', '1', '9'] ['80:']
['142', '55', '1', '9'] ['80'] ['142', '55', '117', '173'] ['3784:']
['142', '55', '1', '9'] ['80'] ['142', '55', '117', '173'] ['3784:']
['142', '55', '149', '106'] ['1591'] ['142', '55', '1', '9'] ['80:']
```

Now I'm trying to to create a dictionary called Hosts where the keys are all the unique IP addresses (src ip + dst ip) those keys are to keep count of how many times the ip addresses are repeated

I assume i have to run everything through an if statement where it adds the IP addresses to the dictionary and keeps a counter of how many times it the same addresses are added.

My trouble is I have the lists created but don't have a clue on how to convert the contents of them into a dictionary.

**EDIT**
The function is supposed to be called Maker. Using Maker to generate a new key/value pair in my dictionary or modifing an exisiting entry. It's suppose to do this for every line in the dump.

```
def Maker(src,dst):
      if src in list(Hosts()):
        #add one to the src counter in Hosts(src) array
      else Hosts[src] = [1,0]

      if dst in list(Hosts()):
        #add one to the dst counter in Hosts(dst) array
      else Hosts[dst] = [0,1]
```

Comment: What should the expected result look like?

Comment: can you also paste the initial text content ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240969/python-count-repeated-elements-in-the-list