# How do I determine which dictionary has the most entries?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary in which the key is a country code, and the value is a dictionary. For each country, the key is one of seven airport types, and the value is a list of airport names.

I'm trying to determine what country has the most airports of a certain type. In other words, which country has the most entries in it's subdictionary for seaplane bases.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Could you please give some example data?

Comment: can you provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hello Robert! Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240969/python-count-repeated-elements-in-the-list/23240989

Comment: `max(list_of_dicts, key=len)` if you just need one, otherwise `heapq.nlargest(n, list_of_dicts, key=len)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, an example would ease the process. BUT if I got you right, you have a dictionary- the key is a name of a country(string) and the value is another dictionary, in which the key is the kind of an airport (string) and the value is a list that concludes the names of all the airports from the same kind in the chosen country. What you are looking for is the country with the most airports from the kind of seaplane bases:

```
maxAirports = 0 #A variable that would flag what are the most airports from the sea plane kinds (initiated to 0)
maxCountry = "" #A variable that would specify the name of the country that was the last one to change the value of maxAirports (initiated to "")

first_dictionary = {your keys and values...}
for country, airports in first_dictionary.items():
    for airport_type, airport_names in airports.items():
        if airport_type == seaPlane_Base:
            if maxAirports < len(airport_names):
                maxAirports = len(airport_names)
                maxCountry = country

print ("The country with the most Sea Plane Bases is " + maxCountry + " and it has " + maxAirports  " airports in total!)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `len()` method which returns the length of, for example, a dictionary or a list like so:

`len(dict)`