# Counting the words in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has fruits that were bought that month.

The dictionary looks like this:

```
bought = {
January: ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Kiwi', 'Raspberry'],
February: ['Orange', 'Mango', 'Banana'], 
March: ['Apple', 'Starfruit', 'Apricot']
}
```

Is there any way that I could list how many times I bought each fruit.

I want the output to look something like this

```
Apple: 2, Banana: 2, Orange: 2, Kiwi: 1, Raspberry: 1, Mango: 1, Starfruit: 1, Apricot: 1
```

All the other places I have use a dictionary to show how many times a word is used in a list. I am looking for a dictionary that finds out how many times a word is mentioned in another dictionary.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The thing is that I only just started learning how to code so I don't know much.

Comment: Go to the python tutorial and look at what you can do with lists.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll try to find out

Comment: @Elnumerodos you might want to take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240969/python-count-repeated-elements-in-the-list/23240989)

Comment: Thank you @system123456 but the link that you sent me was for a list right? I am trying to find the same thing as that but with a dictionary instead.

Comment: ok my mistake...

Comment: See this link for a hint of how to proceed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5829377/7292937

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is to get the counts, so we'll restructure into a new dictionary called `out`:

```
out = {}
for month in bought:
  for fruit in bought[month]:
    out[fruit] = out.get(fruit, 0) + 1
```

This for-loop just goes through all the keys (months) in `bought` and iterates through the list it finds there. As it reads fruits in that list, it checks to see if that fruit is already in `out`. If not, it initializes that fruit in `out` as `0`. Finally, it increments the value by one.

Now we need to print in the format we want:

```
for k in out:
      print("{}: {}".format(k, out[k]))
```

String formatting in Python is *extremely* mature. You can learn all sorts of tricks at https://pyformat.info/ for example. Here we are just inserting the key and then the value to a string template, as we iterate through `out`.

Comment: Thank you so much, This worked perfectly. And thank you for the site too. I'll make sure to check it if I have other problems from now on.

Comment: That's a really good way to do it @Charles Landau. Have my upvote - in my answer, I never thought about just assigning as I go

Comment: I'll test that now :)

Comment: They both have a sys time of 0.010s, but mine is faster in real: 0.164s as opposed to your 0.189. Although I suspect for bigger lists, yours will come out on top - I really like the nested loops. _Tests ran 10 times, on an Intel 8300. 8GB RAM (not really needed but sure) and SSD._

Comment: Very interesting @PrinceOfCreation

Comment: Yes it is, I would have expected yours to come out faster.

Comment: @PrinceOfCreation try it on much larger data if you like

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188935/discussion-between-princeofcreation-and-charles-landau).

Comment: Instead of checking if a key exists you could simply do ```out[fruit] = out.get(fruit, 0) + 1```

Answer (score 2):

I just quickly threw this together.

## Code:

```
bought = {
"January": ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Kiwi', 'Raspberry'],
"February": ['Orange', 'Mango', 'Banana'], 
"March": ['Apple', 'Starfruit', 'Apricot']
}

numbers = {}
allb = []
for month in bought:
    allb += bought[month]
for item in allb:
    if item in numbers:
        numbers[item] += 1
    else:
        numbers[item] = 1
print(numbers) # Note you can format this however you want: just iterate through the dictionary again
```

### Expected Output:

```
Apple: 2, Banana: 2, Orange: 2, Kiwi: 1, Raspberry: 1, Mango: 1, Starfruit: 1, Apricot: 1
```

### Actual Output:

```
{'Apple': 2, 'Banana': 2, 'Orange': 2, 'Kiwi': 1, 'Raspberry': 1, 'Mango': 1, 'Starfruit': 1, 'Apricot': 1}
```

(As `numbers` is a dictionary, you can do very powerful things to lookup numbers. It acts like a table in this case.)

The first `for` loop goes through all the keys in bought (as it is formatted, all the months) and looks up their value. It then adds those values to my list `allb` (all bought)
Next, I iterate through `allb` and `if` the item is already in numbers: I add 1 to the count, otherwise I set the count at 1.

Comment: Thank you as well. This also worked. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Using builtin Counter. One liner :-)

```
from collections import Counter

bought = {
    "January": ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Kiwi', 'Raspberry'],
    "February": ['Orange', 'Mango', 'Banana'],
    "March": ['Apple', 'Starfruit', 'Apricot']
}

count = Counter([y for x in bought.values() for y in x])
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
from pprint import pprint

c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(bought.values()))

pprint(c)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'Apple': 2,
         'Banana': 2,
         'Orange': 2,
         'Kiwi': 1,
         'Raspberry': 1,
         'Mango': 1,
         'Starfruit': 1,
         'Apricot': 1})
```