# Nested For Loop Counter

Tags: python

I am very beginner with Python and am having trouble with a certain aspect of the counter as it relates to its use in a nested for loop.

I am trying to run a nested for loop that checks if an array A has any duplicate values.

Trying to talk myself (and y'all) through this to make sense out of it: I am using a nested for loop to essentially loop through each item in array A...and for each item in array A, I need another counter to loop A so that I can compare A to itself in the form of counter i and counter j. **Here is the issue**: **I don't want to count on itself aka i don't want to double count**. And if I simply type the code that y'all will see below, it will double count (count on itself). **So I want to make sure that the index of my inner for loop's counter is always +1 to my outer for loops counter**.

**Here is what the code looks like:**

```
A = [4, 3, 2, 4]

for i in A:
    for j in A:
        if i == j:
            print("yup")
```

**the output is...you guessed it:**

```
yup
yup
yup
yup
yup
yup
```

6 "yup"'s because each time it is counting each number on itself.

Hopefully I am explaining that properly...

**So my question is: does anybody know how to make sure that my "j" counter is indexed +1...**

**I thought it would be:**

```
for i in A:
    for j = i + 1 in A:
        if i == j:
            print("yup")
```

**but apparently that isn't right**

Any insight here is very much appreciated!!!

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: What is your desired output? An array with unique elements?

Comment: use enumerate() with for loops for indexing. If still confused go with while loops and do natural indexing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to start j from 1 you can simply use the range function

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(A)):
        if A[i] == A[j]:
            print("yup")
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: If you are counting duplicates in a list, I would suggest you use Counter or HashMap which will reduce your time complexity to O(n). You can check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240969/python-count-repeated-elements-in-the-list/23240989)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` to get the current index in the outside loop and then loop over a slice on the inside:

```
A = [4, 3, 2, 4]

for i, n_outer in enumerate(A):
    for n_inner in A[i+1:]:
        if n_inner == n_outer:
            print("yup")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution for your problem. `enumerate` function returns a tuple with the index and value of each array element.

```
for idx_i, elem_i in enumerate(A):
  for idx_j, elem_j in enumerate(A[idx_i+1:]):
      if elem_i == elem_j:
         print("Yup")
```

If you want an  array with unique elements, there are better efficient ways to do that