# Numpy count items in array and store in a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, count

Lets say i have multiple numpy arrays like this: `[1, 2, 4, 7, 1, 4, 6, 8, 1, 8, 2, 5]`

I want to count the number of times each item appears in the array, and store the result in a dictionary:

`{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 0, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 2}`

Is there a faster way to do this than to simply loop over the array and counting the items and storing them in dictionary?

Comment: Or maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Comment: If the values are bounded, you can just `np.bincount`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy, in its wisdom, has functionality for this:

```
np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
```

It does not return a dictionary, but you can easily convert the result into one.

Comment: At least with this small example, `collections.Counter` is faster.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using count:

```
MyList = [1, 2, 4, 7, 1, 4, 6, 8, 1, 8, 2, 5]
my_dict = {i:MyList.count(i) for i in MyList}
print(my_dict)
```

this will definetely work
you will find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23240989/11602126)

I think the below one is the easiest way

```
from collections import Counter
MyList = [1, 2, 4, 7, 1, 4, 6, 8, 1, 8, 2, 5]
print(Counter(MyList))
```

output would be
Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, 4: 2, 8: 2, 7: 1, 6: 1, 5: 1})

Comment: this does work. it is also  _O(N^2)_  . So do not use this for sizeable lists

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in pandas

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = pd.Series([1, 2, 4, 7, 1, 4, 6, 8, 1, 8, 2, 5])
>>> a.value_counts().to_dict()
{1: 3, 8: 2, 4: 2, 2: 2, 7: 1, 6: 1, 5: 1}
```