# list of dicts- get the number of duplications

Tags: python

I have a `list` of `dicts` (same format) like this :

```
L =  [
        {'id': 1, 'name': 'john', 'age': 34},
        {'id': 1, 'name': 'john', 'age': 34},
        {'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna', 'age': 30},
        {'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna', 'age': 30},
        {'id': 3, 'name': 'stack', 'age': 40}
    ]
```

I want to remove duplication and get the number of this duplication like this

```
[
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'john', 'age': 34, 'duplication': 2},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna', 'age': 30, 'duplication': 2},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'stack', 'age': 40, 'duplication': 1}
]
```

I already managed to remove the duplication by using a `set`.... but I can't get the number of duplications

my code :

```
no_duplication = [dict(s) for s in set(frozenset(d.items()) for d in L)]
            
no_duplication =  [
                   {'id': 1, 'name': 'john', 'age': 34},
                   {'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna', 'age': 30},
                   {'id': 3, 'name': 'stack', 'age': 40}
                  ]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Comment: you can see my code

Comment: Look into collections.Counter

Comment: number of dicts - number of not duplication shall give you number of duplication, no ?

Comment: Mathieu, we can't apply Counter to dicts! 
DonKnacki, can you please clarify I didn't get it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: count repeated elements in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240969/python-count-repeated-elements-in-the-list)

Comment: yes i solved the problem thank you all for your help

Comment: `len(L) - len(no_duplication)` don't give you the expected result ? maybe I misunderstood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution you can give a try using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter),

```
from collections import Counter

print([
    {**dict(k), "duplicated": v}
    for k, v in Counter(frozenset(i.items()) for i in L).items()
])
```

---

```
[{'age': 34, 'duplicated': 2, 'id': 1, 'name': 'john'},
 {'age': 30, 'duplicated': 2, 'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna'},
 {'age': 40, 'duplicated': 1, 'id': 3, 'name': 'stack'}]
```

Comment: ah I see using Counter instead of the set, I didn't think about it thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
 ar = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'john', 'age': 34},
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'john', 'age': 34},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna', 'age': 30},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna', 'age': 30},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'stack', 'age': 40}
]

br = []
cnt = []

for i in ar:
    if i not in br:
        br.append(i)
        cnt.append(1)
    else:
        cnt[br.index(i)] += 1

for i in range(len(br)):
    br[i]['duplication'] = cnt[i]
```

The desired output is contained in `br` as:

```
[
 {'id': 1, 'name': 'john', 'age': 34, 'duplication': 2}, 
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna', 'age': 30, 'duplication': 2}, 
 {'id': 3, 'name': 'stack', 'age': 40, 'duplication': 1}
]
```